# Simple example for a set with cardinality of $\aleph_2$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

What is a simple or commonly known set that has a cardinality equal to $\aleph_2$ or greater?

Comment: Greater or equal than that: The powerset of the reals.

Comment: forgot to mention. Other than power sets

Comment: @user84641 Note that it is consistent to assume that every cardinality is some iterated powerset of the naturals. But you could disguise this example by taking "The set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$".

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: But in any case $2^{2^{\aleph_0}} \ge \aleph_2$.

Comment: Oh, ok... @CliveNewstead, now I see the sense of the question. I should've remebered to look at the one in the post and not the one in the title.

Comment: The cardinality of the reals is unknown, is it not? It hasn't been proven that it is $\aleph_{1}$ it is believed that $\aleph_{0}<card(R)<\aleph_{2}$ this is an extension on the unprovable Continuum Hypothesis. The current axioms of set theory imply that we will never know the true cardinality of the reals.

Comment: You could put that a different way. We do know the cardinality of the reals. But we will never know the cardinality of the first aleph, unless CH is assumed. (I mean the first aleph after $\aleph_0$.)

Comment: @AlanU.Kennington What do you mean "unless CH is assumed"? CH is not a axiom it is a hypothesis so one cannot assume it.

Comment: As of 1963, it has been known that both CH and AC are independent of ZF, due to Cohen's results. Therefore you can either assume CH or not assume it. (I won't discuss the difference between CH and GCH.) You get different models depending on whether you assume CH as an axiom or not. Like AC, you can make CH (or GCH) either true, false, or unknown depending on which axiom set you work in.

Comment: @Aleksandar: An axiom is just a statement. You can assume any statement you want. The question is whether or not your assumptions are consistent, or at least "as consistent" as some other sets of assumptions. $\sf ZFC+CH$ is consistent if and only if $\sf ZFC+\lnot CH$ is consistent, so we may assume $\sf CH$ or its negation without worrying that we have introduced a contradiction into our system.

Comment: An axiom is a proposition that is assumed to be true but cannot be proven. Example: $a<b$ then $a+c<b+c$.

Comment: @Aleksandar: No. Not really.

Comment: Definition: a statement or proposition that is regarded as being established, accepted, or self-evidently true.

Comment: @Aleksandar: Don't rely on OED for *mathematical* definitions. Browse this site for the several questions about this (e.g. can you prove an axiom, or what is an axiom, etc.), this has been covered several times. Axioms are just statements that you are starting with. You can assume *any* statement that you want, and you can prove axioms, either from other axioms, or from themselves, or prove they are equivalent to theorems under certain assumptions (e.g., the ***AXIOM*** of choice is equivalent to Zorn's ***LEMMA*** over $\sf ZF$, by which we mean that we can *prove* the axiom of choice there).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with alephs, other than $\aleph_0$, is that they don't really live in the 'commonly known' world. Think of the sets that are commonly known by mathematicians:

- Finite sets;
- Number sets $\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$, which have cardinality $\aleph_0$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$;
- Power sets, which have cardinalities of the form $2^{\kappa}$;
- Function sets, which have cardinalities of the form $\kappa^{\lambda}$;
- Sets of sequences (see function sets);
- Products and unions of sets, which have cardinalities of the form $\kappa\lambda$ or $\kappa + \lambda$;
- ...and so on.

The realm of the 'commonly known' consists of cardinals formed from finite cardinals and $\aleph_0$ by taking powers, sums and products, not cardinal successors.

I'd say the most commonly known set of cardinality *equal to* $\aleph_2$ is the (von Neumann) ordinal $\omega_2$, or indeed any ordinal $\alpha$ for which $\omega_2 \le \alpha < \omega_3$.

However, we can certainly construct cardinals which are *greater than or equal to* $\aleph_2$. Indeed, we know that $2^{\kappa} > \kappa$ for all cardinals $\kappa$, so
$$2^{2^{\aleph_0}} > 2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad 2^{2^{\aleph_0}} \ge (2^{\aleph_0})^+ \ge \aleph_0^{++} = \aleph_2$$
and hence any set of cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ will do for you. For instance $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ or $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, both of which are sets appearing in (say) real analysis.

Comment: Just as a side issue, I've always wondered what even $\omega_1$ looks like. I know it's greater than $\epsilon_0$ because $\epsilon_0$ is countable. I wonder just how far you have to go to either get to $\omega_1$ or at least know for sure that you have gone past it. And then $\omega_2$ is obviously something way out beyond that. It's a great inconvenience that no one seems to know what $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are. At least none of my 45 books on logic and set theory contain this information.

Comment: @AlanU.Kennington: That might make a nice MSE question...

Comment: So out side of this highly abstract set theory these cardinalities don't have any implications in the real world

Comment: That is in fact correct. If you do not assume CH (or GCH), you have a dangling aleph which is not identifiable with any set in standard ZF set theory without AC or CH. The only way you get such cardinality sets is in weird models which are really just like ZF sets, but because of the way the model's interpretation is constructed, they look like they have weird cardinalities within the theory. I've been examining this very topic for a few years, and finally it clicked that you will only ever find such cardinality sets in model theory, not in plain old ZF.

Comment: On a closely related topic, I was looking for a set which is greater than $\aleph_0$ but smaller than $2^{\aleph_0}$. I finally found these things in abundance in a 1958 paper by Azriel Lévy, "The independence of various definitions of finiteness", Fundamenta Mathematicae, volume 6, pages 1–13. If you look that up, you will get some idea of what these sets look like. But allow 2 years to learn the prerequisite model theory first if you're not an expert in that.

Comment: @Alan: I think that there have been several questions as to how to visualize uncountable ordinals. The answer is easy, you don't. Just like you can't visualize the size of a super-giant red star. You just think about the sun, in red, and larger. $\omega_1$ is so large, that any "reasonable" property of its order already occurs uncountably many times before it. So there's no real way to understand it in a different way than $\varepsilon_0$, for example.

Comment: @user84641: That is not true. If there are various objects which exist on $\omega_1$ or on $\omega_2$, you can sometimes deduce information about the structure of the real numbers, on measurable sets, and on Borel sets. If those are useless as well, then yes, uncountable cardinals are "essentially meaningless". But those are not that useless after all.

Comment: To see an example for @Asaf's claim: Let $\mathcal F$ be a family of entire functions s.t. for every $z \in \mathbb C$ the set $\{ f(z) \mid f \in \mathcal F \}$ is countable. Question: Is it true that $\mathcal F$ is countable? Paul Erdös noted that this question has a positive answer if and only if the continuum hypothesis fails. I'd like to argue that this demonstrates the use of cardinalities outside of "abstract set theory".

Comment: aleph 1 lives in the commonly known world, no?

Answer (score 0):

Sets of ℵ2 cardinality are quite uncommon but it seem we have some example with real closed fields : under continuum hypothesis, all real closed fields of ℵ1 cardinality that also satisfy η1 property (that is : for two subsets A and B  of cardinality less than ℵ1, such as any element of A is less than any element of B, there is an element of X greater than any element of A and less than any element of B) are isomorphic to the hyperreal field F, which is apparently not complete, that is it is included and dense in an ordered field K, and its completion K is of cardinality ℵ2.